# Listview cacheColorHint having problem?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to scroll the item in listview. It works properly with (android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"). But, now i want to scroll with selecting item only should change it's color like orange. How to do this? Is it Possible? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please give details. Problem statement is not clear.

Comment: Yes, I'm having one listview contains some items. If i'm going to press and scroll the item it'll show that selected item's background as orange color. How can i done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

provide this attribute to change the background color of the list item selected.

```
 android:listSelector="#FFFF"
```

Comment: Sorry. try now. I have edited my answer. Your selected item will be displayed in white. You can change to what ever color you like.

Comment: What will i give to change the color in orange.